# função que retorna letra de mapeamento dos drivers em delphi

Tags: delphi

Preciso de uma função ou comando em `Delphi` que retorne a letra do mapeamento dos drivers do usuário.

exemplo: `Z:`, `U:`

Answer (score 0):

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Types;

// Returns an array filled wit the assigned
// drive letters on the current computer.
function  GetDriveList: TStringDynArray;
var
  Buff: array[0..128] of Char;
  ptr: PChar;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  if (GetLogicalDriveStrings(Length(Buff), Buff) = 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  // There can't be more than 26 lettered drives (A..Z).
  SetLength(Result, 26);      

  Idx := 0;
  ptr := @Buff;
  while StrLen(ptr) > 0 do
  begin
    Result[Idx] := ptr;
    ptr := StrEnd(ptr);
    Inc(ptr);
    Inc(Idx);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, Idx);
end;

// Converts a drive letter into the integer drive #
// required by DiskSize().
function DOSDrive( const sDrive: String ): Integer;
begin
  if (Length(sDrive) < 1) then
    Result := -1
  else
    Result := (Ord(UpCase(sDrive[1])) - 64);
end;

// Tests the status of a drive to see if it's ready
// to access. 
function DriveReady(const sDrive: String): Boolean;
var
  ErrMode: Word;
begin
  ErrMode := SetErrorMode(0);
  SetErrorMode(ErrMode or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  try
    Result := (DiskSize(DOSDrive(sDrive)) > -1);
  finally
    SetErrorMode(ErrMode);
  end;
end;

// Demonstrates using the above functions.
var
  DrivesArray: TStringDynArray;
  Drive: string;
const
  StatusStr = 'Drive %s is ready: %s';
begin
  DrivesArray := GetDriveList;
  for Drive in  DrivesArray do
    WriteLn(Format(StatusStr, [Drive, BoolToStr(DriveReady(Drive), True)]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

**Saída:**

```
Drive C:\ is ready: True 
Drive D:\ is ready: True
```